# compiling boost gives argument error

Tags: boost, centos7

I'm getting an argument error, when trying to compile boost 1.66.0 for centos7. I'm new to boost and/or compiling, so I'm stuck. Any idea would help.

```
# compile command used:
wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.66.0/source/boost_1_66_0.tar.gz
tar -xzf boost_1_66_0.tar.gz && cd boost_1_66_0
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/opt/boost
./b2 install --prefix=/opt/boost --with=all
```

The error I get is:

```
[root@app1 boost_1_66_0]# ./b2 install --prefix=/opt/boost --with=all
/tmp/boost_1_66_0/tools/build/src/build/toolset.jam:43: in toolset.using
*** argument error
* rule python.init ( version ? : cmd-or-prefix ? : includes * : libraries ? : condition * : extension-suffix ? )
* called with: ( run: /usr/bin/python -c import sys; print (%d.%d % (sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1])) 2.7 : run: /usr/bin/python -c import sys; print(sys.prefix) /usr :  :  :  :  :  :  )
* extra argument /usr/bin/python
/tmp/boost_1_66_0/tools/build/src/tools/python.jam:104:see definition of rule 'python.init' being called
/tmp/boost_1_66_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:1052: in using
project-config.jam:23: in modules.load
/tmp/boost_1_66_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:249: in load-config
/tmp/boost_1_66_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:412: in load-configuration-files
/tmp/boost_1_66_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:524: in load
/tmp/boost_1_66_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import
/tmp/boost_1_66_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
/tmp/boost_1_66_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have python installed. Likely, you don't have other build essentials installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you sehe that was the issue - boost picked up a different version of python which wasn't stock python libraries. That fixes the issue.